# How to get an existing aws account into Landing zone?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, boto3, aws-service-catalog, aws-landing-zone

I have done with the Landing zone solution setup with initial template which provided by AWS.

Now,I have one existing account and I want to get that account into my landing zone.

Answer (score 0):

The landing zone requires configuration and baselines to be set on an account. I think the way the scripts are configured expects a new account. I do not know a way of importing existing account into the Landing Zone for now.

Furthermore, it might be dangerous to add an existing account into the landing zone as it may break the workloads in it.

Consider creating a new account via the landing zone and migrate your workloads into it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using aws organizations you can bring the existing account in to organizations , based on ou the account ll be mappped